# Which fontspec CharacterVariant values are available?

Tags: fontspec, ebgaramond

The `fontspec` package allows me to do this:

```
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic} very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:0] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:1] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:2] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:3] very
```

to produce this output:

[image]

How do I know which values of `CharacterVariant` I can use? Specifically, how do I know that `CharacterVariant=5` refers to the letter v?

Comment: Look at the documentation http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ebgaramond/doc/Specimen.pdf

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike, that answers the question for EB Garamond. But I wonder if there is a general way to know this. If I have an OpenType font file, is there any tool I can run that will tell me what character variants the font provides?

Comment: You can use otfinfo, but it will not tell you details, only the name of features.